# Exercise, show inequality(measure theory).

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This exercise resembles what we do when we create the Lebesgue measure, but it is not quite the same.

> An interval can be any type:
>   $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b],(a,a),[a,a],[a,\infty],[a,\infty],(-\infty,b),(-\infty,b]$.
>
> Assume that $\{C_n\}_n$ is a countable collection of intervals, and
>   also assume that C is an interval with $C \subset \cup C_n$.
>
> Show that $l(C)\le\Sigma_nl(C_n)$, where the length of the intervals are
>   defined in the obvious way.

In solving this I tried 3 different cases.

1. One $l(C_n)=\infty$.
2. $l(C)<\infty$, all $l(C_n)<\infty$
3. $l(C)=\infty$, all $l(C_n)<\infty$

I have a suggested solution for 1 and 2, can you please se if you agree, on 3 I do not know what to do, so here I need help.

1. This is trivial, beacuse the RHS is then immediately infinity.

2.Given $\epsilon$ , if C is not closed, close it, and cover the endpoints of intervals of length $\epsilon$. Get a countable enumaration of all the intervals endpoins for the $C_n$, if any of these intervals are closed at one or more end-point, open them, but then cover the point you opened with an interval of length $\epsilon/2^n$.

Then we have a compact set, with an open covering, so it must have a finite subcovering. It is easy to check that if we have a finite number of intervals, covering an interval, the sum of the intervals must be bigger or equal then the interval it covers, so we get:

$l(C)$ $\le \Sigma_{\text{finite subcovering}} l(C_k)\le\Sigma_nl(C_n)+3\epsilon$. Hence $l(C)\le\Sigma l(C_n)$.

Is this correct?

3. Do you have any tips for the case where $l(C)=\infty$, but all the other intervals are finite?

**PS: If you do not want to check or give hints, but have your own solution, I would also appreciate that.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for part 2 is correct.

As for part 3, if $l(C) = \infty$ you can let $k \ge 1$ and let $I \subset C$ be an interval with $k < l(I) < \infty$.  Since $I \subset \cup C_n$ you obtain by (2)
$$ k < l(I) \le \sum_n l(C_n).$$ Now let $k \to \infty$ to conclude $$\infty = \sum_n l(C_n).$$